# Can I monitor daemon/service with supervisord?

Tags: linux, service, daemon, supervisord

I have a system-V init service/daemon running my application. I wanted to make sure that my application always runs even with conditions where process/service could crash, machine restart. I know of supervisord which is able to monitor process but I am not sure it can monitor service/daemon ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the manual [advices against it](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html).

There is [an answer to a similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/608069/managing-daemons-with-supervisor-no-foreground-mode-available) which provides a workaround.

Anyway, I would try to find a way to have that service stay in the foreground.